# Return function only after ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I have this function in Java:

```
public int[] getProperties() {
    properties = new JFrame();
    properties.setSize(400, 200);
    properties.setVisible(true);
    properties.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    propertiesPanel = new JPanel();
    propertiesPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 10, 5);
    properties.add(propertiesPanel);

    heightText = new JLabel("Height (squares)");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    propertiesPanel.add(heightText, constraints);
    heightField = new JTextField(5);
    heightField.setText(Integer.toString(board.getHeight()));
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    propertiesPanel.add(heightField, constraints);

    widthText = new JLabel("Width (squares)");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    propertiesPanel.add(widthText, constraints);
    widthField = new JTextField(5);
    widthField.setText(Integer.toString(board.getWidth()));
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    propertiesPanel.add(widthField, constraints);

    multText = new JLabel("Pixels per Square");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    propertiesPanel.add(multText, constraints);
    multField = new JTextField(5);
    multField.setText(Integer.toString(board.getMultiplier()));
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    propertiesPanel.add(multField, constraints);

    confirm = new JButton("Ok");
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    propertiesPanel.add(confirm, constraints);

    final int[] dimensions = new int[3];
    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dimensions[0] = Integer.parseInt(heightField.getText());
            dimensions[1] = Integer.parseInt(widthField.getText());
            dimensions[2] = Integer.parseInt(multField.getText());
            properties.dispose();
        }
    });

    return dimensions;
}
```

(the `JFrame`, `JPanel`, `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s are all defined in other places). However, the function always returns an array like this: `{0, 0, 0}` because `confirm` is never pressed immediately. So, how do I return `dimensions` only after `confirm` is pressed?

Comment: Please clear the context what u wanna acheive with that....

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this in one of two ways:

- block your program's execution until the user enters a set of dimensions

this would be done by wrapping your form inside a modal [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html), displaying that JDialog, waiting for the user to close the JDialog, then examining the contents of `widthField` `heightField` and `multField`.

- use some sort of callback to be notified when the user has entered a set of dimensions

this would be done by passing some kind of listener class as an argument to `getProperties` and then invoking it from inside your `ActionListener`.